# Как сверстать тему на Bootstrap для OpenCart?

Tags: bootstrap, opencart

Посоветуйте какие-нибудь статьи, в которых описывается как натянуть свёрстанный на bootsrap макет на OpenCart. С фреймворком Bootsrap я знаком и умею верстать с его помощью, а темы для CMS еще ни разу не делал. В моем случае мне надо сделать тему для интернет магазина, который работает на OpenCart.

Comment: Первая ссылка по запросу "opencart make template": http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-theme-with-opencart-introduction--cms-21786

Comment: хотелось бы на русском

Comment: Вы простите конечно, но вас что, в гугле забанили? google->opencart разработка шаблона

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего на готовых примерах разбираться. https://opencartforum.com/files/file/1396-bootstrap3 
Готовый бесплатный шаблон Bootstrap3 для 1.5 версии, а если второй OpenCart использовать, то там по умолчанию Bootstrap.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку!

Answer (score 0):

дефолтная тема OC свёрстана на Bootstrap, по сей день на 3 версии, при установке на BS4 придётся переименовать десяток классов.